# innerHTML not displaying

Tags: javascript

Apologies for asking such a trivial question (just learning how JS works) but I am getting a headache for next to nothing. Maybe I am tired and just don't see what I am doing but why is the below not working - i.e. value of totalBits to print in the body of the 'print' div? If I alert() it shows the value but not using the innerHTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function answer(sentence){

var bitsOfString = sentence.split(" ");
var numOfBits = bitsOfString.length;
return numOfBits;
}

var sentence = prompt("OK, say something!")
var totalBits = answer(sentence);
var div = document.getElementById("print");
div.innerHTML = totalBits;

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="print"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are calling it before the element is rendered to the page. Move the script after the element is loaded or you can call your code window onload/document ready.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="print"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function answer(sentence) {    
        var bitsOfString = sentence.split(" ");
        var numOfBits = bitsOfString.length;
        return numOfBits;
      }

      var sentence = prompt("OK, say something!")
      var totalBits = answer(sentence);
      var div = document.getElementById("print");
      div.innerHTML = totalBits;

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, my days people, I must be asleep! Of course I am trying to call it before the parser. Cheers! Ok, I am off to bed. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your error console. You should get `div is null` as an error, because the element hasn't been parsed yet.

You need to put your script block *after* your `div` element or defer the execution of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your JavaScritpt executes before the DOM is ready.

In other words, wrap your javascript where you manipulate the div in `document.onload` function or if you're happy to use jQuery: `$(function(){});`

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/c8tyg/

P.S.
I'm not the fan of moving the `<script>` blocks around because IMHO JavaScript should work regardless how you load it on the page. You're manipulating DOM - respect the game - wait for the DOM to load.

Comment: Small note: a partial DOM tree is completely sufficient, as long as the element's subtree is complete.

Comment: Where is the jQuery tag? How will jQuery help this user?

Comment: "or if you're happy to use jQuery"